# TypeError While Adding Tuple To Another Tuple

Tags: python, tuples

So why do I get this error? - Picture 1

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISZA6.png)

And is corrected by simply putting a comma? - Picture 2

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apfQy.png)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for tuples yet?

Comment: Don't post links to images; put the relevant information in the question itself, as text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

- In picture 1, you're add two different shapes (4,) and (1,).
- In picture 2, the shapes are automatically turned to equal (4,) by python. Though I still recommend always keeping equal shapes when writing code, because you never know when you might get an error for unequal sizes/shapes - especially with large arrays/sizes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what in the world do you mean by shapes in python?

Comment: the shape of your tuple - the first one has 4 values and the second one that youre adding has a shape of 1 - which is why you get an error in picture 1